# display hyperlink as icon and not text

Tags: html

I have the following code for displaying files that are saved on the database/server:

```
$value .= "<a target=_blank href='https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.iso365.online/flashpoint/".$fileArray[$i]["name"]."'>View</a>";
```

On the web page this displays the value as a hyperlink which is displayed as

> View

.

What I want to do is change the text from View to an icon, which would be

> images/view.jpg

.

Can someone please tell me how to modify the above code to make this happen, thanks.

Comment: Well, replace _View_ with an `img` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so that code is not only HTML (it looks like PHP, so you might want to add that tag).

But regardless, you want to change the text `View` to an image element.

```
<img src="images/view.jpg">
```

So the code should be:

```
$value .= "<a target=_blank href='https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.iso365.online/flashpoint/".$fileArray[$i]["name"]."'><img src='images/view.jpg'></a>";
```

Notice the use of single quotes instead of double quotes (`src='...'` instead of `src="..."`), as double quotes are the string delimiter and will end your string early.

Comment: yes i tried that, as in $value .= "<a target=_blank href='https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.iso365.online/flashpoint/".$fileArray[$i]["name"]."'><img src="images/view.jpg"></a>";   BUT I am getting an error = syntax error, unexpected 'images' (T_STRING)

Comment: What you pasted above ^ is different than my answer. You placed the `src` inside `a` instead of inside `img`

Comment: Also, you must use `src='images/view.jpg'` instead of `src="images/view.jpg"` (single quotes instead of double quotes). This should solve your syntax error. This is because you are trying to put quotes in a string that's already delimited by a double quote, so single quotes must be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<a target=_blank href='https://docs.google.com/viewer url=http://www.iso365.online/flashpoint/".$fileArray[$i]["name"]."'>
    <img src="link to your image here..."></img>
</a>
```